Need Help Regarding Licensing for Samsung Kernel Sources
I'm planning to push Samsung Kernel Source to GitHub and need some guidance on the appropriate licensing. Specifically, I'm wondering:

What license should I use for the Samsung Kernel Source?
Can I simply copy the licensing approach used in this repository: android_kernel_samsung_sm8550?



What license should I use for the Samsung Kernel Source?

Whatever license you received the source code under, assuming that license allows you to push it to Github at all.
The answer here is probably "GPL version 2 only" but that's not something we can answer for you.
